# How to update variable in Singleton pattern

Tags: swift, singleton, ios13

I have singleton class has lan variable .it is simple like this

```
class Settings{
    //  singelton
    static let shared  = Settings()
    var lan:String? = "ar"
      
 
    private init(){
    
    }
 
}
```

and I have a button which change language code for application from ar to en and when I tabbed it again language code changed from en to ar .

```
    @IBAction func languageBtnTabbed(_ sender: Any) {
        
        MOLH.setLanguageTo(MOLHLanguage.currentAppleLanguage() == "en" ? "ar" : "en")
        print(MOLHLanguage.currentAppleLanguage())
        Settings.shared.lan = MOLHLanguage.currentAppleLanguage()
        
        MOLH.reset()
       
        
    }
```

my question is how to update lan variable on setting class with "MOLHLanguage.currentAppleLanguage()"

I tried to update lan variable by using this line :
Settings.shared.lan = MOLHLanguage.currentAppleLanguage()
but in the fact the lan variable did not change .
can any one help me to solve this problem ?
and thanks in advance.

i tried to didset{} on lan variable to update it once the language code is changed and the code worked well .

Comment: Your code should work. Could you add `print("Settings.shared.lan: \(Settings.shared.lan)")` just before `MOLH.reset()` to display any change.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Are you sure MOLHLanguage gets updated when you update MOLH? Off topic but I would suggest you create an enum for your languages even if they are only two to make your code cleaner and avoid spelling errors.

Comment: yes my code is working and language code is changed only inside my function

Comment: How is MOLHLanguage kept in synch with MOHL?

Comment: are you saying that the `print("Settings.shared.lan: \(Settings.shared.lan)")` just before`MOLH.reset()` as I suggested, does not show the change in `lan`?

Comment: My Code is working in languageBtnTabbed() and the language code is changed well after reset() but the lan variable in settings class still hold the intial value "ar" i want to change the lan variable once language code is changed in languageBtnTabbed()

Comment: does not show the change in lan? yes , their is no change in lan variable

Comment: Since you are ignoring my comments I see no point in spending any more time trying to help you.

Comment: thank you very much it is solved the solution is didSet{} on  lan variable  to update it once the language code changed on languageBtnTabbed()

Answer (score -1):

So it might be worth checking what the value of `MOLHLanguage.currentAppleLanguage()` is, I suspect that the value of `MOLHLanguage.currentAppleLanguage()` is actually `ar` perhaps?

try changing the default text for `land` to something like `default` and see if value now updates to `ar` when you run your code.

Comment: I want to understand why lan variable did not change and still hold the initial value "ar"

Comment: thank you I make didset{} on lan variable and the code working well now.class Settings{
    //  singelton
    static let shared  = Settings()
     var  lan : String = "en"
    var defaultLan  = ""  {
        didSet{
            lan = defaultLan
  
        }
    }

    private init(){
         
    
    }
 
}